# Error during publish NET 6 app to AWS Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, visual-studio-2022

I am trying to publish my NET 6 Svc to AWS Lambda from VS 2022.

1. Created the file %USERPROFILE%.aws\credentials
   [default]
   aws_access_key_id=xxxx
   aws_secret_access_key=yyyy
2. Right click on project, Publish AWS Serverless Application

Here I see the profile: default, Region: Europe(London)
and Stack name: 
S3 Bucket:

The buttons Next, Publish are greyed.
Ok, I am trying to create new S3 Bucket but after some seconds it wrote: Error: creating S3 Bucket: The authorization header is malformed : the region 'us-east-1' is wrong, expecting 'eu-west-2'
I do not see where is us-east-1.

Btw, I do not see all fields as described there:
https://codewithmukesh.com/blog/aws-lambda-with-net-6/

May be I do not need to create the S3 Bucket but what need I fix?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the [AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio](https://aws.amazon.com/visualstudio/), you can open the AWS Explorer and view/edit your profile to make sure it has the correct region.

Also, "Publish AWS Serverless Application" is a little different from "Publish to AWS Lambda". If you are only publishing to Lambda, you can just use the option to publish the Lambda project to AWS Lambda and you should not need an S3 bucket.

Comment: I have full functional ASP.NET 6 app and want to deploy it to AWS Lambda. AWS Explorer does not deploy the app to Lambda. It deploys NET Lambda but not ASP.NET app.  How to do it? Any links?

Comment: An ASP.NET 6 app of what type? It will need to be compatible with Lambda in order to deploy there. This might be [helpful](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/deploy-an-existing-asp-net-core-web-api-to-aws-lambda/)

Comment: I have created it  using AWS template: AWS Serverless app (NET Core)

Comment: The link to blog in the comment is quite old -2017. More recent article https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/csharp-package-asp.html#csharp-package-asp-deploy-api